# jQuery drag and drop is not working with mobile touch

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, touch, windows-mobile

I am using **jQuery** drag and drop library, but its working well in web browsers but not working in mobile touch. Here is my html and javascript ..

*P.S. I want to get **this** value so that I can handle multiple boxes with different attributes, that's why I have called the **hover** function,*

```
<!-- html -->

    <div>
        <ul class="draggable">
            <li class="dragme">one</li>
            <li class="dragme">two</li>
            <li class="dragme">three</li>
            <li class="dragme">four</li>
            <li class="dragme">five</li>
            <li class="dragme">six</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<!-- style -->

ul.draggable {list-style: none; }
ul.draggable li {display: block; width: 100px; height: 40px; background-color: #000; color: #fff; margin-top: 20px; text-align: center;}

<!-- javascript -->

       function drags() {
            jQuery('.dragme').hover(function () {
                var dragContent = jQuery(this);
                jQuery(dragContent).draggable({revert: true});
            });
        }
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            drags();
        });
```

I also added this functions (below) to enable touch in mobile it was working well first but, now its not working... I had found it here in **stackoverflow**

```
 <!-- touch functions -->

 function touchHandler(event) {
            var touch = event.changedTouches[0];

            var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
            simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent({
                touchstart: "mousedown",
                touchmove: "mousemove",
                touchend: "mouseup"
            }[event.type], true, true, window, 1,
                    touch.screenX, touch.screenY,
                    touch.clientX, touch.clientY, false,
                    false, false, false, 0, null);

            touch.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
            document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
            document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
            document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
        }
     // -- call **init()** in document.ready function
```

Please help with your answers

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should move everything into an [Anonymous Self-Executing Function](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/).

Next, you should not be initializing the draggable stuff on hover. It happens inside the Self-Executing Function when the page loads.

By default jQuery draggable is not friendly with mobile. You should also use this... http://touchpunch.furf.com - It fills in the gaps in jQueryUI to make drag and drop better on mobile.

By adding TouchPunch, it will just work automatically on mobile. No additional code needed. As a test, if you remove TouchPunch from the jsFiddle, you will see it does not work again.

On the drag call back, we get the element currently being dragged (ui.helper), from this you can pull any attributes or data you want.

```
(function(){

    $('.dragme').draggable({
        revert: true,
        drag: function (e, ui) {
            var elem = $(ui.helper),
                id = elem.attr('id'),
                data = elem.data('example');

            $('h1').text(data + ' being dragged! #' + id);
        },
        revert: function (e, ui) {            
            $('h1').text('---');
            return !e;
        }
    });

})();
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3vx3bdf9/)

Look at External resourses in this fiddle. You will see jQueryUI and Touchpunch

Comment: This is working perfectly,
but how can I get the element information when it has been dropped, because I need to calculate height and put into drag grid also the information where I am dropping so that I can copy the text  from it and put into dragged element.

Comment: This is now going away from your original question. Here is more info to do stuff when the user drops the helper. https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

. Also, take a look here.. http://jsfiddle.net/3vx3bdf9/1

I added the stop callback, the ui object contains a lot of usefull stuff, you can still get the dragged element with ui.helper

Comment: For drop zones etc... you must use droppable.. There are some nice demos here... https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: OK, Then I will create another question there you can comment. :) 
Thank you

Comment: Not the best solution: if the element to drag takes the whole viewport, using jQuery UI Touch Punch prevents the document to be scrolled. Can be even a problem with element you want to be only draggable horizontally with a container hiding overflow, as a draggable carousel. In this case, the carousel prevents user to scroll the document up and down. I prefer jQuery Touch (github.com/ajlkn/jquery.touch) which makes draggable possibly touch only on mobile (mouse gesture can be filtered) and does not prevent touch events to propagate (thus, document to be scrolled).

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to the scrolling action overriding. Add `touch-action: none;` CSS style to your `.draggable` class